# Chaining two observables http and storage

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, observable, chaining

I am trying to chain two observables. I'm working with the Ionic2 framework. The first observable tries to get an access token out of a mobile device and then second observable then calls the api with that access token. But for some reason the second observable never gets called even tho I subscribed to the chain.

What am I missing?

```
this.observableChain = Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('accessToken'))
  .map(accessToken => this.http.post('http://1234/user/login', {'accessToken': accessToken}))
  .subscribe(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `flatMap()` instead of `map()`?

Comment: Flatmap had fixed it. Thanks a lot. Could you explain to me why this fixed it?

Comment: I could try to explain it but i'm just learning Observables myself using Ionic2 so hopefully this link helps you - http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html.  The simple rule is that if you need to return the stream of another observable (or in your case make another http request) then `flatMap()` is your friend.  I can post it as an answer if you like.

Comment: Go ahead. Thanks for the link that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When chaining observables you need to use `flatMap()`.

```
Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('accessToken'))
    .flatMap(accessToken => 
        this.http.post('http://1234/user/login', {'accessToken': accessToken})
    )
    .subscribe(
        result => console.log(result), 
        error => console.log(error)
    );
```

A good explanation of this concept is found here - http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Answer (score 0):

You have subscribed, but there is no such thing as subscribing to the chain. Your first observable emits an observable, which is never subscribed to. Basically you have to do something like this:

```
obs1.subscribe(obs2 => obs2.subscribe(result => ...))
```

HTH